# on the variance of sample mean times estimated coefficient

Tags: regression, variance

Consider a simple regression model $Y_i = \alpha + \beta X_i + u_i, (i=1,...,n)$ where $(Y_i,X_i)$ is a random sample. Let $\hat{\beta}$ be the OLS estimator of $\beta$ and $\bar{X}$ be the sample mean of $X_i$ given by $\bar{X}=n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

I'm trying to derive $Var((\hat{\beta}-\beta)\bar{X})$. If $X_i$ is fixed(nonrandom), it is easy to derive. But when $X_i$ is random, I have no idea how to derive this variance since $X_i$ appears both in the numerator and denominator in $\hat{\beta}$.

Any comments/answers would be appreciated!

Comment: Consider applying the "law of total variance" by conditioning on $X = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$.  The answer of course, depends on how $X$ is distributed, so a closed-form is unlikely to exist.